# R - lost seasonality effect of time series after 12 diff

Tags: r, time-series, arima, seasonality

I tried to fit time series model. Below is the plot of my original series by `tsdisplay(mydata_ts)`.

[image]

I think it's quite clear that there is no trend but only seasonality in this series. So, I did 12 lags diff and this resulted in the following ACF and PACF below.

[image]

[image]

It seems that ACF and PACF lost the effect of seasonality. The confusion is should I include the seasonality effect in my SARIMA(6,0,5)(0,1,0)12 or should I simply use ARIMA(6,0,5)? Then again does ARIMA(6,0,5) seem to be too complex to use AR(6) and MA(5)? Any thought will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that both  the options are the same . You should not even see any coeficients for the seasonal part in the Sarima model part of the model with both P, Q = 0 .
You can also compare the two models using AIC or BIC  on a test data set to be sure .